# Analyze / Sniff all packets from all devices connected to a router

Tags: network, router, wireshark, monitoring, sniffing

First of all, before explaining what I'm trying to do, let me clarify that my intentions are not steal any information, as it's only for study purposes, not even for my own entertainment.

I'm trying to analyze / sniff all packets which are sent or received from any device connected to my router which is exposed to the Internet. I'm currently using Wireshark on Windows 10, yet after filtering the packets that are being logged, the only ones I can recognize are the ones that are sent/received from my device, not others (I have access to router connected devices IP and MAC addresses).
I did some basic googling and I found out that if I enable monitor mode, it's possible to analyze other devices packets, which I still can't after enabling it.

So my question remains, is it really possible to sniff all packets from all devices connected to a router using a sniffing software like Wireshark? Because from my point-of-view that it's not possible since I'm a "device" and not the "device manager".

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your router or (switch) if it supports `port mirroring`, where you will be able to duplicate the packets transmitted through Mirrored Port to Mirroring Port. This function allow network administrator to capture packets of a specific port to monitor the network or troubleshoot. So you can mirror the port of your internet connection to your laptop.

If you don't have this function in your router or switch, then use the following solution for temporary sniffing/analyzing:

1) I connect my laptop to the internet using Ethernet cable,
2) then share internet using WiFi hotspot,
3) connect all device I want to analyze to the WiFi hotspot,
4) open up Wireshark on my laptop and listen to the Ethernet port.

Comment: In short, there is no way to sniff packets from other devices. correct ? 

Not even on open network (wifi network without password)?

Comment: Yes we can't unfortunately. Can we talk a bit about this `port mirroring`? 

I'm also writing some test cases for IPSec protocol and that would be very useful, but also dangerous!

About `port mirroring`, only one who has privileged access to the router can achieve that. Right?